# A question on pseudocompact spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is there a pseudocompact space with a $G_\delta$-diagonal the cardinality of which is greater than $\mathfrak c$?

Comment: Your question will receive much more attention if you could add a sentence defining pseudocompact and also perhaps a couple of sentence on Mrowka spaces.

Comment: [Mrowka space](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M.V. Matveev at page 39 in his “[A survey on star covering properties](http://at.yorku.ca/v/a/a/a/19.ps)” wrote:

[image]